# ANTLR operator precedence broken by optional right recursion?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm confused by the behavior of this grammar (in ANTLR 4.8):

```
grammar Bug;
stat: expr ';' ;

expr:   expr '*' expr?
    |   expr '+' expr
    |   '(' expr ')'
    |   INT
    |   ID
    ;

ID  :   [a-zA-Z]+ ;
INT :   [0-9]+ ;
WS  :   [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip ;
```

That's a minimal modification of an example from the book; all I've done is add a `?` to the first alternative for `expr`, so that `*` can be either a postfix unary operator or a binary operator.

To my surprise that seems to break the logic around binary operator precedence:

- without the `?`, `3*4+5;` parses as `(stat (expr (expr (expr 3) * (expr 4)) + (expr 5)) ;)` (as expected)
- with the `?`, `3*4+5;` parses as `(stat (expr (expr 3) * (expr (expr 4) + (expr 5))) ;)` (wat?)

Is this a bug, or is this behavior expected?  How do I get the behavior I was hoping for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is expected behavior... However, the more readable grammar like this seems to do what you expect it to (and preserves precedence):

```
expr:   expr '*' expr #MulExpr
    |   expr '+' expr #Addxpr
    |   expr '*'      #PointerExpr
    |   '(' expr ')'  #NestedExpr
    |   INT           #IntExpr
    |   ID            #IdExpr
    ;
```

The `#...Expr` after each alternative are called [labels](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md#alternative-labels).

Comment: Thanks, that's a good workaround.  I'm still curious about whether the behavior of the original version is a bug, but this is no longer causing me problems.